# How can I pull in all xml nodes that are one of two types of nodes with Linq-to-xml?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am parsing through HTML using Linq-to-sql.  Right now to get a specific paragraph tag I'm using the following code:

```
        var paragraphs = contentDiv.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Elements("p").ToList();
```

However, one of the sites I am parsing has P tags with  tags after them.  So the markup is like:

```
<p>...</p>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<p>...</p>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<p>...</p>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<p>...</p>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
```

I need to get all the text inside all `p` tags and inside all `ul` tags but I need the content in the order that it appears in the HTML.  Essentially I'd like something similar to:

```
        var paragraphs = contentDiv.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Elements("p" || "ul").ToList();
```

How would I go about doing this?

And no, these P and UL tags are not sectioned off by themselves, so I can't just get all content in that parent XElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want

```
contentDiv.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Elements()
          .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "p" || x.Name.LocalName == "ul")
          .ToList();
```